# How can i combine these fields using join query in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am building an API. I have 2 tables Products and Product to category mapping.
Products have multiple category.i'm not using Model.

```
DB::table('products_to_categories')
    ->LeftJoin('products', 'products.products_id', '=', 'products_to_categories.products_id')
    ->LeftJoin('categories_description','categories_description.categories_id','=','products_to_categories.categories_id')
    ->leftJoin('manufacturers','manufacturers.manufacturers_id','=','products.manufacturers_id')
    ->leftJoin('manufacturers_info','manufacturers.manufacturers_id','=','manufacturers_info.manufacturers_id')
```

Currently i'm getting the output

```
{
    "products_id": 12,
     "categories_id": 1,
     "categories_description_id": 1,
     "categories_name": "Animal Figures",
},
{
     "products_id": 12,
     "categories_id": 2,
     "categories_description_id": 4,
     "categories_name": "Arts Crafts",
}
```

I want to combine both and get an output of

```
{
     "products_id": 12,
     "categories_id": [1,2],
     "categories_description_id": [1,4],
     "categories_name": ["Animal Figures","Arts Crafts"]
}
```

Comment: you cant get that with query. you can use a foreach after getting result and combine them

Comment: Is there any way to do with the merge() method

Comment: first of all, check laravel relations. They are much easier once you understand them. If you want to use this way than check sql `concat`
Also your `leftJoin` should be always written `leftJoin` instead of `LeftJoin`